# Colon Preventing String Methods in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

We just switched our phone system over to Teams, and one of the things I'm trying to do is update our AD records to reflect the numbers since some users got new DIDs. Since we're not using extensions anymore, my priority is removing phone numbers listing extensions in AD.

I created this script which should get a list of everyone with an extension in the phone number field in AD, check their number in Teams, and then update the AD field.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

$usersToUpdate = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties telephoneNumber | where {($_.telephoneNumber -like ("x")) -and $_.Enabled -eq $True} | select userprincipalname,telephonenumber,samaccountname

foreach ($user in $usersToUpdate) { 
$teamsNumber = Get-CsOnlineUser $user.userprincipalname | select OnLinePremURI 
Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samAccountName -OfficePhone $teamsNumber 
}
```

BUT here comes the issue. The OnLinePremURI returns an object with a colon in it, eg "tel:+15555555555."

As such, I can't run any string manipulation methods (eg .Substring(), Insert(), .ToString()) on it to change the format to include hyphens in the phone number in AD, eg 555-555-5555.

Is there a way to manipulate that OnLinePremURI so I can get it to that desired formatting?

Comment: What does get-member show for OnLinePremURI?

Comment: Why should a colon in the string prevent any string methods to work? Make sure the value OnLinePremURI is actually a string.

Comment: Change `select OnLinePremURI` to `select -expand OnLinePremURI` or `ForEach-Object OnLinePremURI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mathias suggersted in the comments you need to work with the value of the `OnLinePremUri` not the object with the sole property by the same name, that would be produced by `Select-Object`.

However, after that using simple string manipulations are available, below is an example.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

$usersToUpdate = 
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties telephoneNumber | 
Where-Object {($_.telephoneNumber -like ("x")) -and $_.Enabled -eq $True} | 
Select-Object userprincipalname,telephonenumber,samaccountname

foreach ($user in $usersToUpdate) { 
    $teamsNumber = (Get-CsOnlineUser $user.userprincipalname).OnLinePremURI
    $teamsNumber = ($teamsNumber -replace '^tel:\+1').Insert(3, '-').Insert(7, '-')
    
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samAccountName -OfficePhone $teamsNumber 
}
```

Simply replace the first part of the string with nothing then run the `.Insert()` method on the results once for each "-" you want to add.

Warning: If you are dealing with foreign numbers and / or other perhaps unpredictable formats you may need to adjust from there.  Nevertheless, given the question this is a good starting point.

Comment: Yep, Mathias' comment absolutely nailed it. I ended up going with

$teamsNumber.SubString(6).Insert(3,'-').Insert(7,'-')

instead of your exact commands, but it gives me the desired output.

Comment: Same, Same. Glad it worked out.  Sorry for the extra answer, I hadn't yet seen the string manipulation part addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$teamsNumber = Get-CsOnlineUser $user.userprincipalname | select OnLinePremURI 
Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samAccountName -OfficePhone $teamsNumber
```

To either this:

```
$teamsNumber = Get-CsOnlineUser $user.userprincipalname | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OnLinePremURI 
$teamsNumber = $teamsNumber.Substring($teamsNumber.IndexOf(':') + 1)
Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samAccountName -OfficePhone $teamsNumber
```

Or this:

```
$teamsNumber = Get-CsOnlineUser $user.userprincipalname | select OnLinePremURI 
$teamsNumber = $teamsNumber.OnLinePremURI.Substring($teamsNumber.OnLinePremURI.IndexOf(':') + 1)
Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samAccountName -OfficePhone $teamsNumber
```

Or however you wish to format the number.